# How to get morphological variation, given a lemma (java preferred)

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, lemmatization

I'm currently using Stanford Core NLP to get word lemmas from text. Is there any way within the Stanford suite to run this "in reverse"? For example, suppose I have the lemma "come" and I want to get the gerund form ('VBG' POS tag) "coming".

If this isn't available in the Stanford suite, can anyone recommend a different Java tool that can accomplish this?

Comment: CoreNLP does not do this, as far as I know. Perhaps an online dictionary would be a first step in the right direction?

Comment: I found this [wiki page at ACL](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Morphology_software_for_English) of morphology tools, though haven't used any yet. It looks like CoreNLP uses "morpha" and there is a "morphg" that runs in reverse... I guess that's not in CoreNLP?

I'd prefer to avoid just scraping a dictionary if possible...